# Why does this Stored Procedure work from Server Explorer, but not when called by an SSRS Report or my app?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I recently updated a Stored Procedure; I changed the last part of it from this:

```
SELECT 
    TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName, 
    TC.WEEK1USAGE, TC.WEEK2USAGE, TC.USAGEVARIANCE,
    TC.WEEK1PRICE, TC.WEEK2PRICE, TC.PRICEVARIANCE, 
    TC.PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE
FROM 
    #TEMPCOMBINED TC
ORDER BY 
    TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName;
```

...to this:

```
SELECT 
    TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName, SUM(TC.WEEK1USAGE), 
    SUM(TC.WEEK2USAGE), SUM(TC.USAGEVARIANCE), 
    AVG(TC.WEEK1PRICE), AVG(TC.WEEK2PRICE), AVG(TC.PRICEVARIANCE), 
    SUM(TC.PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE)
FROM 
    #TEMPCOMBINED TC
GROUP BY 
    TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName
ORDER BY 
    TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION;
```

to eliminate some duplicate records I was getting (the `PlatypusDESCRIPTION` and `MemberName` combination should always appear on one row).

It works just fine from Server Explorer; I can execute the stored procedure, provide the parameters, and it returns the data I expect.

However, the SSRS report that uses this stored procedure no longer works - it leaves the values for all columns from `TC.WEEK1USAGE` on blank (only the values for `PlatypusDESCRIPTION` and `MemberName` display); and when I run it from my custom Winforms app that calls the SP, it gives me an error message about the table not having a field named "" What?!? That field is there, as you can see.

Why would the stored procedure run in Server Explorer, but balk when called from SSRS and elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly give the aggregated fields names like this:

```
SELECT TC.PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName, SUM(TC.WEEK1USAGE) AS WEEK1USAGE, SUM(TC.WEEK2USAGE) AS WEEK2USAGE, 
SUM(TC.USAGEVARIANCE) AS USAGEVARIANCE, AVG(TC.WEEK1PRICE) AS WEEK1PRICE, AVG(TC.WEEK2PRICE) AS WEEK2PRICE, 
AVG(TC.PRICEVARIANCE) AS PRICEVARIANCE, SUM(TC.PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE) AS PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE
FROM #TEMPCOMBINED TC
GROUP BY TC.PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName
ORDER BY TC.PLATYPUSESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName;
```

IOW, "*SUM(TC.WEEK1USAGE)*" does not cut it; it must be of the form "*SUM(TC.WEEK1USAGE) AS WEEK1USAGE*" (etc.)